# Spring context initializtion failed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the below exception when I trying run the maven project

SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.JdkVersion.isAtLeastJava15()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:128)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5370)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5668)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 23, 2018 11:26:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [spring-mvc] in web application [/SpringMvcUser] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.JdkVersion.isAtLeastJava15()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:128)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5370)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5668)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

help me to solve this exception

Comment: check you have older version of spring in your classpath

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc for class `org.springframework.core.JdkVersion` says:
Deprecated. as of Spring 4.2.1, in favor of direct checks for the desired JDK API variants via reflection

In Spring version 4.2.6 there is no method `isAtLeastJava15()` in class `JdkVersion`.

Some of your code seems to be written for an an older version of Spring. Are mixing up different versions or is a library you are using requiring another version? Have you checked your classpath?

Comment: Thanks for your comment jeysee, The call was happening from getOperationInfo(..) method of spring-jmx-2.0.8.jar.But we are seeing this issue only on specific environment not on all the environments

Comment: I suggest to check, if all your application servers or your environments are configured in the same way. Maybe some of them are configured to add special jar files to the application's class pat hat runtime?